# How to execute a powershell command on remote computers?

Tags: powershell, windows-server, windows-server-2016

I have the following file that I need to run on several dozen servers:

```
powershell -file "\\server\share\appInitInstall.ps1"
```

How can I run it without having to RDP into each one of them?
I am successful at running a script block on remote computers:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName server01, server02 -ScriptBlock {Get-UICulture}
```

but how does one run a file on other PCs?

Comment: You need some server on the remote computers, and there is some protocol involved. Maybe [SSH](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/windows/)

Comment: You are looking to do a double hop. If you go look for "PowerShell double hop" on the internet there's lots of blogs and articles about this issue.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Yep, that was it.  Very unintuitive.